# How to query if multiple items exist in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of ids and I want to check which of them exist in my DynamoDB in an efficient way.

For example my list of ids might be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And my DynamoDB table named Cats has the following:

```
{id: 1, name: 'cat1'}, {id: 3, name: 'cat3'}, {id: 5, name: 'cat5'}
```

I would like to know with one call that ids 1, 3, 5 are in my DynamoDB. Not sure if this is possible with 1 get request or if I need to make 5 gets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer depends on how is your data structure.

[Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) requests must contain the id of the entity, so there is no way to do 1 query request and fetch all three results.

[Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) requests could fetch all entries (or a filtered version of them, based on your list) but, depending on how big your table is, that request can be quite expensive from a time perspective.

Another option might be to create a [secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) based on some other semantic your data might have and do a query/scan on that.

Take a look at the dynamodb [Best Practices](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html) page to see if you can improve your table structure to facilitate the operations.